# Test if parameter is with specific value

Tags: python, google-translate

Is it possible to test with `if` or other functions that a variable has a specific value passed in a specific argument?

For instance here is a line of code that detects the language of a string of text. I need to perform a test to conclude if the text is in English. This information passed inside the argument `lang` which would be `lang=en` in case of English. If `lang` is not `en` for variable `language` I will then perform the translation to English.

The gola is not to translate text that is in English to be more efficient. Or maybe it is more efficient to just let `googletrans` translate English to English and not perform the test at all? What would be more efficient - to translate from English to English or to perform the check that I intend. I will have to translate many thousands of strings.

```
from googletrans import Translator

words = ['Many', 'like', 'name', 'kas', 'jauni burti']

translate = Translator()
for language in words:
    print(translate.detect(language))
```

Result

```
Detected(lang=en, confidence=1.0)
Detected(lang=en, confidence=1.0)
Detected(lang=en, confidence=0.95300263)
Detected(lang=lv, confidence=0.43629345)
Detected(lang=lv, confidence=1.0)
```

Comment: Please, do not mix several questions in to one post. Concerning `if`, do you mean `if variable == value`? Concerning perfomance, just measure it.

Comment: Question was how to test if the detected language is English. Please see each detection results. It has a 'lang' argument. I need to perform further operations with words that are not in Emglish, so the question was how to test if the 'lang' argument does not have value 'en'

Comment: The question is "Is it possible to test with if or other functions that a variable has a specific value passed in a specific argument?" The answer is `if variable == value` or `if variable != value`. It can be `if lang == "en"`. It is really not clear what you want, that's why I was asking

Comment: If you will write just if lang == "en" you will receive an error with reason "unresolved reference 'lang' ". How do you tell in the if test that 'lang' is an argument for variable and not just a variable by itself?

Comment: what is "argument for variable" and "variable by itself"? Please update your question, there is no `lang` variable / argument in your code.. It is really unclear in this form

Comment: What Im saying is that if you would write the code like in your previsous response "if lang == "en", then the "lang" would be treated as a variable that, as you already pointed out, does not exist. Please see the Result section of the original code. Result is "Detected(lang=lv, confidence=1.0)". You can see there argument "lang" here. simple if lang == "en" would not work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Testing specific value

A few notes about terminology:

- variable ... a "named free object", e.g. `words`, `word` or `detected` below
- parameter ... function input used in function definition, e.g. `text` in [detect documentation](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator.detect)
- argument ... specific value passed to a function/method, e.g. below `word` is argument passed to `translate.detecct`
- attribute, member ... member variable of a class/instance/object/..., e.g. `lang` and `confidence` are attributes of `Detected` instances.

OP is asking for *parameter*, *variable* and *argument*, but what is actually wanted is an **attribute**.
Next time please use proper terminology to prevent confusion.

An example how it could work:

```py
from googletrans import Translator

words = ['Many', 'like', 'name', 'kas', 'jauni burti']

translate = Translator()
for word in words:
    detected = translate.detect(word)
    print(detected)
    if detected.lang == "en":
        print("   ","English")
    else:
        print("   ","not English!")

# print(dir(detected))
```

Note, [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) returns all available *attributes* of passed *argument*.

#### Performance

According to [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/), `googletrans` uses Google Translate Ajax API , most likely involving some network operations. So you should measure the performance yourself, preferably on a target system.